# Confuse on proof of theorem 22.9 (White-path theorem) Depth-First search (DFS) on Cormen-Leiserson-Rivest-Stein "Introduction to algorithms" book

Tags: algorithms

I'm reading the DFS section of CLRS-*Introduction to Algorithms*, and confuse on the $\Leftarrow$ direction of the proof of the white-path theorem of DFS algorithm in this book. 
Note that each node u in the graph has 2 **timestamps**: $u.d$ records when u is discovered and $u.f$ records when the search ﬁnishes examining u’s adjacency list .

Dependencies:

> **Theorem 22.7 (Parenthesis theorem)**
> In any depth-ﬁrst search of a (directed or undirected) graph $G = (V, E)$, for any
> two vertices u and v, exactly one of the following three conditions holds:
>
> - the intervals $[u.d, u.f]$ and $[v.d, v.f]$ are entirely disjoint, and neither u nor v
>   is a descendant of the other in the depth-ﬁrst forest,
> - the interval $[u.d, u.f]$ is contained entirely within the interval $[v.d, v.f]$, and u
>   is a descendant of v in a depth-ﬁrst tree, or
> - the interval $[v.d, v.f]$ is contained entirely within the interval $[u.d, u.f]$, and v
>   is a descendant of u in a depth-ﬁrst tree.

> **Corollary 22.8 (Nesting of descendants’ intervals)**
> Vertex v is a proper descendant of vertex u in the depth-ﬁrst forest for a (directed
> or undirected) graph G if and only if $u.d < v.d < v.f < u.f$.

Proof of theorem 22.9:

> **Theorem 22.9 (White-path theorem)**
> In a depth-ﬁrst forest of a (directed or undirected) graph $G = (V, E)$, vertex v is
> a descendant of vertex u if and only if at the time $u.d$ that the search discovers u,
> there is a path from u to v consisting entirely of white vertices.
>
> **Proof** $\Rightarrow$: If $v = u$, then the path from u to v contains just vertex u, which is still white when we set the value of $u.d$. Now, suppose that v is a proper descendant of u in the depth-ﬁrst forest. By Corollary 22.8, $u.d < v.d$, and so v is white at time $u.d$. Since v can be any descendant of u, all vertices on the unique simple
> path from u to  in the depth-ﬁrst forest are white at time $u.d$.
>
> $\Leftarrow$ Suppose that there is a path of white vertices from u to v at time $u.d$, but v does not become a descendant of u in the depth-ﬁrst tree. Without loss of generality, assume that every vertex other than v along the path becomes a descendant of u.(Otherwise, let v be the closest vertex to u along the path that doesn’t become a descendant of u.) **Let $w$ be the predecessor of v in the path, so that $w$ is a descendant
> of u (w and u may in fact be the same vertex)**. By Corollary 22.8, $w.f \leq u.f$ . Because v must be discovered after u is discovered, but before w is ﬁnished, we have $u.d < v.d < w.f \leq u.f$ . Theorem 22.7 then implies that the interval $[v.d, v.f]$ is contained entirely within the interval $[u.d, u.f]$. By Corollary 22.8, v must after
> all be a descendant of u.

In the proof, they **let $w$ be the predecessor of v in the path**. How do we know that such a $w$ exists?

Comment: This question will get more attention on https://cs.stackexchange.com/. So it might be a good idea to ask it there.

Comment: What is your final question? Did you mean "How do we know that such a w exists?"

Comment: @ChaitanyaChavali yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption in proving the second part is that there exists a path from $u$ to $v$ in which all the vertices are white(and that $v$ is not a descendant of u in the DFS forest).

Let that path be $$<u, w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4,...w_p, v>$$

$$w=\begin{cases}
       w_p &\quad\text{if }p>0\\
       u  &\quad\text{if }p=0\\ 
     \end{cases}$$

There can be multiple, say $n_1$, paths from $u$ to $v$. Out of them only $n_2$ paths($n_2 \leq n_1$) may be containing all white vertices. Out of those $n_2$ select any one path and use it for your proof. You can select any such path. The proof would still be valid. In each of those $n_2$ paths, there may be a different predecessor to $v$. We select one of those paths and we call the predecessor in that path as $w$.

Comment: why we know $w$ in <w1, w2,..., wp> path? Can it in another path? If we explain that wp is descendant of u, and w is predecessor of v, so that v is descendant of u is obvious. I think the proof need not include theorem 22.7 and corollary 22.8.

Comment: There can be multiple, say $n_1$, paths from $u$ to $v$. Out of them only $n_2$ paths($n_2 \leq n_1$) may be containing all white vertices. Out of those $n_2$ select any one path and use it for your proof. You can select any such path. The proof would still be valid. In every such path out of $n_2$ there is a predecessor to $v$. We select one path and we call the predecessor in that path as $w$.

Comment: @minhquýlê It might look obvious to us, but that doesn't mean that we have proved that implication. If w is a descendant of u and w is the predecessor of v, it does not directly follow that v is a descendant of u. Please understand that there is a difference in the term descendant and predecessor. Firstly, simply saying that `w is the predecessor of v` makes no sense. Predecessor in what?

Comment: If we knew that v is a descendant of w in the DFS forest, then what you are saying is right. But when we say that w is a predecessor of v, we are saying that w comes just before v in `some` path containing all white vertices. Being a predecessor in `some` path does not mean that it is also the ancestor in the DFS forest.

Comment: In Introduction to Algorithms, they define predecessor: whenever depth-ﬁrst search discovers a vertex v during a scan of the adjacency list of an already discovered vertex u, it records this event by setting v’s predecessor attribute $v.\pi$ to u. And v is descendant of u iff v is discovered during the time in which u is gray (after $u.d$ and before $u.f$). So i think it directly implies that v is descendant of u when u is descendant of v. Is it right?

Comment: But in the proof, the authors are not referring to that definition of predecessor. `Let  be the predecessor of v in the path`. Here the phrase `in the path` is crucial. By `predecessor`, they mean the vertex occurring before v in that white path(in the assumption).

Comment: Also if you have found my answer and the following discussion useful, consider marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: about $v.d$ < $w.f$, i explain that if $v.d$ >= $w.f$ then v is discovered after $w$ finish, which is a contradiction be cause v in $w$'s adjacency list of $w$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Because by the time $w.d$, $v$ is still white and there is an edge from $w$ to $v$, it has to be discovered before $w.f$